# Normal order vs Applicative order procedure in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Let's say I would like to know if the interpreter in scheme/racket is in normal order or applicative order.

```
(define normal?
  (lambda()
    (let ((e (display 'not-)))
      (display 'normal))))
```

This will print normal on normal order and not-normal on applicative order, but can I write a procedure that will do the same for applicative order (meaning display applicative when on applicative order and display not-applicative on normal order)?

My thoughts is this isn't possible because if applicative order procedure terminates it has to return with the same result of the normal order.

Comment: This sounds familiar; it may be a duplicate of a question already out there.  E.g., a search for applicative and normal and scheme on Stack Overflow turns up [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=applicative+normal+order+scheme+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor or we can search on SO itself: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscheme%5D+applicative+normal+order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, this is elementary with mutation, dear Watson:

```
(define applicative?
  (lambda ()
   (let ((test #t))
    (let ((e (begin (set! test #f) #f)))
      (if test (display 'normal) (display 'applicative))))))
```

You didn't forbid mutation, right? But if you insist, use `call/cc` for a hasty exit:

```
(define applicative?
  (lambda ()
   (call/cc (lambda (exit)
    (let ((e (begin (display 'applicative) (exit #f))))
      (display 'not-applicative))))))
```

By now you see that Scheme is not lambda calculus.

Here's a third solution for you. Define `display1` to print its argument only on the very first invocation, and do nothing on any subsequent ones, then use

```
(define applicative?
  (lambda()
    (let ((e (display1 'applicative)))
      (display1 'not-applicative))))
```

Just as you're using a side-effecting primitive in your code, so do I! :)

Comment: "if the interpreter in scheme/racket"  I think Racket forbids mutation by default, but this would work in Scheme.  (However, it does depend on the special evaluation semantics of **if**, which may be problematic.

Comment: I don't see what should be the difference in **if** semantics at all, between the two cases. I was thinking `set!` would be much more iffy. :) But I think under _lazy_ operational  semantics (i.e. stored lambda w/ memoization) `set!` would work as expected.

Comment: @WillNess thanks for the answer,but I was looking for a solution without mutation (with no set!)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Mutation of variables works the same in Racket and Scheme. Racket has immutable cons-cells though (as default).

Comment: @WillNess My point was that if an interpreter were entirely applicative, then **if** might evaluate all three of its arguments and return one of the latter two based on the value of the first.  Of course, that's not how we expect **if** to work for control flow (though in terms of values returned, it would be identical (except for side effects like mutations, etc.).

Comment: I like the bit with call/cc, but I still wonder if that's sort of avoiding the real issue here.  Usually the difference between normal and applicative order comes up in learning about evaluation strategies for the lambda calculus.  The lambda calculus doesn't have mutation, conditional evaluation, or call/cc.  These answers are good, but seem to skirt around the issue by looking for more advanced language constructs.

Comment: @WillNess It wouldn't be a *control* flow if, but it would still be a completely correct *value* if.  E.g., `(if (> 2 3) (+ 1 2) (+ 4 5))` should *return* 9, and it doesn't matter (from a return value point of view) whether `(+ 1 2)` was ever evaluated or not.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor of course it is, avoiding it. The code by OP is equally *not* lambda-calculus; they use side-effecting `display`. I'm not sure if it can be done in LC at all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor right; just that it is not what we're used to, in Scheme. Dijkstra (? was it he ?)  wrote  e.g. about concurrent `if`, that evaluates all its branches and produces the first non-nil value or something...

Comment: @WillNess "I'm not sure if it can be done in LC at all."  I **think** that's the question that OP is looking for an answer to.

Comment: @WillNess your answer is very useful but I did look for a solution in LC,and I'm pretty sure its impossible

Comment: @user3453625 of course it is trivial to write a lambda expression with diverges under applicative order but converges under a normal order evaluation (e.g. [`(λx.1) ((λx.x x) (λx.x x))`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms)). but if it returns a value - i.e. converges - I'm pretty sure it's the same value regardless of the way the reduction was done. AFAIR, something about diamond property. see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14587274/849891).

Answer (score 1):

### Base Analysis

One observable difference between applicative and normal order is the behavior of logical [dead code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code) paths containing procedures that raise errors/exceptions.

### Implementation

In `#lang racket`, we can write a simple test suite utilizing a local function `foo` of arity = 2. The first argument is live within `foo` and the second argument is dead. We then pass a value [`(/ 1 0)] that raises an exception when evaluated down the dead code path.

Wrapping it all up in the testing framework lets us work on our good habits:

```
#lang racket/base

(require rackunit
         rackunit/text-ui
         racket/function)

(define evaluation-order

  (let ((foo (lambda (x y) x)))

    (test-suite
     "Test the evaluation order."

     (test-exn  
       "Applicative Order Test"
        exn:fail?
       (thunk (foo (+ 1 0)
                   (/ 1 0))))

     (test-not-exn
       "Normal Order Test"
       (thunk (foo (+ 1 0)
                   (/ 1 0)))))))

(run-tests evaluation-order)
```

### Sample output

```
racket@29657169.rkt> ,enter "/media/ben/Data/Programming/StackOverflow/29657169.rkt"
--------------------
Test the evaluation order. > Normal Order Test
Normal Order Test
FAILURE
name:       check-not-exn
location:   /media/ben/Data/Programming/StackOverflow/29657169.rkt:19:5
params:     #<procedure:temp5>
message:    "Exception raised"
exception-me"/: division by zero"
exception:  #(struct:exn:fail:contract:divide-by-zero "/: division by zero" #<continuation-mark-set>)
Check failure
--------------------
1 success(es) 1 failure(s) 0 error(s) 2 test(s) run
1
```